# Core Data modifications not saved in two of three tables (maybe because of a previous Core Data migration?)

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I'm a bit lost because of a problem I never experienced before, however, I have a suspicion. I use Core Data for data storage and DB Browser for SQLite for inspecting the database running in the Simulator.

Here's the relevant function where all Core Data handling happens:

```
/**
 Creates a new ComposedFoodItem from the ComposedFoodItemViewModel.
 Creates the related FoodItem and the Ingredients.
 Creates all relationships.
 
 - Parameter composedFoodItemVM: The source view model.
 
 - Returns: A Core Data ComposedFoodItem; nil if there are no Ingredients.
 */
static func create(from composedFoodItemVM: ComposedFoodItemViewModel, generateTypicalAmounts: Bool) -> ComposedFoodItem? {
    debugPrint(AppDelegate.persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions) // The location of the .sqlite file
    let moc = AppDelegate.viewContext
    
    // Create new ComposedFoodItem (1)
    let cdComposedFoodItem = ComposedFoodItem(context: moc)
    
    // No existing composed food item, therefore create a new UUID
    cdComposedFoodItem.id = UUID()
    
    // Fill data
    cdComposedFoodItem.amount = Int64(composedFoodItemVM.amount)
    cdComposedFoodItem.numberOfPortions = Int16(composedFoodItemVM.numberOfPortions)
    
    // Create the related FoodItem (2)
    let cdFoodItem = FoodItem.create(from: composedFoodItemVM, generateTypicalAmounts: generateTypicalAmounts)
    
    // Relate both (3)
    cdComposedFoodItem.foodItem = cdFoodItem
    
    // Add cdComposedFoodItem to composedFoodItemVM
    composedFoodItemVM.cdComposedFoodItem = cdComposedFoodItem
    
    // Save before adding Ingredients, otherwise this could lead to an NSInvalidArgumentException (4)
    try? moc.save()
    
    // Add new ingredients (5)
    if let cdIngredients = Ingredient.create(from: composedFoodItemVM) {
        cdComposedFoodItem.addToIngredients(NSSet(array: cdIngredients))
        
        // Save new composed food item
        try? moc.save()
        
        // Return the ComposedFoodItem
        return cdComposedFoodItem
    } else {
        // There are no ingredients, therefore we delete it again and return nil
        moc.delete(cdComposedFoodItem)
        try? moc.save()
        return nil
    }
}
```

What the function does:

1. Creates a new entry in table ComposedFoodItem
2. Creates another new entry in another table FoodItem
3. Relates both entries
4. Saves the modifications (and as of here I can see both new
   entries in the DB with all relations created correctly)
5. Creates another 1..n entries in a third table Ingredient and links these to
   the entry created in step 1

All this works fine, I can see all relations and entries in the database.

Then I quit and restart the app. The entry created in step 2 is still there, but the entries created in steps 1 and 5 are gone, as well as the relationships (of course).

My suspicion: I recently implemented a Core Data migration from Data Model version 1 ("EasyFPU") to version 2 ("EasyFPU 2"). In this migration, I have two custom migration policies for exactly the two tables, which are not stored. The migration policies are pretty simple (and identical for both tables):

```
/**
 No Ingredient is created in the destination model, i.e., there will be no Ingredients
 */
override func createDestinationInstances(forSource sourceIngredient: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws {
    // Do nothing on purpose
    debugPrint("Not migrating Ingredient with ID: \((sourceIngredient as? Ingredient)?.id.uuidString ?? "unknown")")
}
```

And what I suspect is, that this migration policies are somehow called when restarting the app, but I have no idea why, because the migration has already happened before. If I set a breakpoint in the debugPrint line of the code snippet above, I actually never reach this breakpoint - as expected. Nevertheless are the two tables Ingredient and ComposedFoodItem empty after restart.

My AppDelegate Core Data persistentContainer variable looks like this:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "EasyFPU")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

I tried to replace "EasyFPU" with "EasyFPU 2", but this apparently is not the version, but the container name.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Migration won't keep happening, because it's based on the model hash, which changes because of migration. For it to not change, the migration would have to fail somehow. You can check on this by using the [migration debug flag](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/).

Comment: But a couple of things I wonder about in the code: (1) You only use `moc` for the `ComposedFoodItem`, not for the others, which seems odd. (2) Your step 4 shouldn't be necessary-- I don't know why that exception would occur or why saving changes would prevent it.

Comment: @TomHarrington, thanks for the comments. I also use moc for the other ones, it's just "hidden" in the respective create(from:) function. I will, however, remove step 4, although I remember that I got an NSInvalidArgumentException once. All that will most probably not solve my core problem.